# PCB Design - Polygon pour remove islands or not?

Tags: pcb, copper-pour

Sometimes a polygon pour (I use Altium, so I am using it's naming reference, for other packages it can be power plane and etc.) makes a dead copper area, and the software gives you the option to remove it or no, but why someone will want to not remove it? The only reason I can think someone will want a dead copper area is to make fabrication faster since there will be less copper to remove, and to make it cheaper since less chemicals will be used. 
Is this right? Or there are other options that I cant see?
Thank you!

Comment: As an aside, usually it's good to give a day, if not a little longer, to give people a chance to see a question and give you answers.  While my answer could potentially be 100% correct, answering early will lead to some people not throwing in their thoughts as well, which could give even more information.  Not a warning or reprimand or anything... just a little friendly advice. :)

Comment: Oh, good advice! didnt think about it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certainly not the only reason, but a big one is **copper thieving**.

When manufacturing a board, it's easier to control consistency when the board has equal copper coverage.  It helps avoid over/under-etching, helps balance the board's rigidity, and so on.  If you had huge open areas without a copper pour, and let the manufacturer do copper theiving, they might add a pattern of dots or diamond shapes, not connected to any net, to add more copper to the board to balance it.

A reason that you might not want these unconnected pour islands, or the dots/diamonds added by the board house, could be for reasons like controlled impedance or EMI.  In this case, you might end up telling the board house to specifically not do copper thieving in certain areas of the board... or you might choose to have those pour islands be tied to ground.

In this case, you'd be leaving the unconnected pours on there yourself, not necessarily telling the manufacturer to add *more* copper to your board... but it's the same idea.