# What is a polygon island in Altium?

Tags: altium

So what exactly is a polygon island in altium and why is it generally considered bad? How can they be removed from the PCB?

Comment: Related: [PCB Design - Polygon pour remove islands or not?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/48677/6334)

Answer (score 1):

Islands are floating pieces of copper in the PCB, in most designs they are harmless, in some they are not. In a vacuum such as space space radiation can charge any [floating piece of metal and cause it to discharge](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/2003ESASP.540....3C) and damage materials and electronics. So, no islands for space designs.

They can be removed by checking remove islands or:

Remove Islands Less Than

Remove any areas of copper that are less than the specified area. This option is area-based only; it does not consider if that island is connected to a pad or via. Note that all small unconnected areas of copper are always removed if the Remove Dead Copper option is enabled in the Properties panel.
Source: https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-obj-polygonpourpolygon-pour-ad?version=18.1

Answer (score 0):

> So what exactly is a polygon island in Altium

This is explained in the [online documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-obj-polygonpourpolygon-pour-ad):

> > Remove Islands Less Than
> >
> > Remove any areas of copper that are less than the specified area. This option is area-based only; it does not consider if that island is connected to a pad or via. Note that all small unconnected areas of copper are always removed if the Remove Dead Copper option is enabled in the Properties panel.

It's a small part of the polygon that is unconnected to the rest of the polygon due to other objects like tracks or vias.

> How can they be removed from the PCB?

By checking the box for "remove islands less than" and choosing the maximum island area in the polygon properties dialog.